# Passing existing matrix into JAGS model using R package rjags

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

Very simple question, but I somehow cannot find a solution.
How would you pass existing value(matrices, vectors) into JAGS model using rjags?

Here is a sample code:

```
model{
      A = inverse(B)
     }
```

And somehow I want to pass `B = diag(100)` into the model above, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass data to a model with the `data` arg to `jags.model`:

For example:

```
library(rjags)

M <- 'model {
  A <- inverse(B)
}'

j <- jags.model(textConnection(M), data=list(B=diag(10)), n.chains=3)
jags.samples(j, 'A', 1000)
```